# Print value to two decimal places in ruby

Tags: ruby

My goal is to print some values with 2 decimal places.  The values are contained within "begpoint".

```
begpoint = begpoint/100    
printf "%.4f \n", begpoint
```

current output:

```
4252.0000
2739.0000
2632.0000
10505.0000
```

for brevity here are the raw values:

```
425215
273944
263291
1050589
```

this is what I **expect** to see:

```
    4252.15
    2739.44
    2632.91
    10505.89
```

It looks as though its just printing a few zeros at the end!

Comment: "Decimal places" are different to "Significant figures". For example, 4252.15 has 2 decimal places, but 6 significant figures. Likewise, 0.012 has 3 decimal places, but only 2 significant figures. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Significant_figures Please clarify whether you're asking about "decimal places" or "significant figures".

Comment: Thanks Andrew...adjusted question s/sigfigs/decimal places , hope that helps clarify.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to divide by a float and specify `2f` to `printf`, like in the following:

```
begpoint = begpoint/100.0  
printf "%.2f \n", begpoint
```

e.g:

```
point = 425215/100.0
printf "%.2f", point # => 4252.15
```

Relevant: [`Kernel#printf`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Kernel.html#method-i-printf)
and [`Kernel#sprintf`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Kernel.html#method-i-sprintf)

Comment: Thank you!  This worked like a charm...learn something new everyday.

Comment: @fatu, you could please accept and upvote my answer if its what you wanted

Comment: The OP is confused about the difference between significant figures and decimal places, and this answer fails to point out the difference between the two concepts.

Comment: @fatu you should accept correct answers, that's how it works on SO